# OnPropertyChanged Event in WCF DataContract

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm fairly new to WCF implementations and I'm having difficulties with some databinding.  Namely, I have 2 radio buttons inside my silverlight application (the properties are bound to properties inside one of my data contracts).  I also have a masked text box that changes based on the radio button selected.  The "Masked Textbox"'s text is bound to another property of the data contract of the WCF.

My thought process was to implement the "INotifyPropertyChanged" interface on the data contract and use the "OnPropertyChanged" event that would trigger the masked textbox to change its "mask" based on the radio button selected. Well this hasn't worked out so well as i'm unable to get the OnPropertyChanged event working properly from the WCF.

Do you guys have any workarounds to this hopefully trivial problem?

Thank you so much in advance,
-Tom

Comment: Is the data contract declared on a shared assembly? Have you checked that when creating the Service Reference, a new data contract type is not created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I needed by creating a wrapper class on the client side (that extended the WCF's data contract).  I then implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on this wrapper class.  It might not be the prettiest workaround but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Your phrase "I'm unable to get the OnPropertyChanged event working properly from the WCF." triggers some warning bells.

Is the data being modified on the client or the server?

You have to understand that if a WCF service returns an object to the client, then the client has a *copy* of this object, not a *reference*. Any events thrown by the server's copy of the object will not be received by the client.

If you want data notifications to be triggered by the server and received by the client, you will have to implement this using a duplex (two-way) binding. You cannot implement server-to-client notifications using .NET events (at least, not for the distributed communication part).